# Insert spaces between string in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array('16 HOURS','13.3 HOURS','10.6 HOURS AGO','8 HOURS AGO','5.3 HOURS AGO','2.6 HOURS AGO','CURRENT')
```

I want to insert empty cells ('') between every string until the desired length is reached. I have tried various loops, for i etc but always end up with white spaces behind CURRENT or before 16 HOURS, thanks in advance.

Comment: what are those various loops can we know?? this is insufficient data!

Comment: http://php.net/array_splice

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: Say I want this array `array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')` to be 13 in length it will look like `array('1','','2','','3','','4','','5','','6','','7')`

Comment: @user1990896 See my answer below.

Comment: @user1990896 show your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$array = array('16 HOURS','13.3 HOURS','10.6 HOURS AGO','8 HOURS AGO','5.3 HOURS AGO','2.6 HOURS AGO','CURRENT');

$i = 1;

foreach($array as $val) {
  $tempArray[] = $val;
  if($i < count($array)) {
    $tempArray[] = '';
  }
  $i++;
}

print_r($tempArray);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16 HOURS
    [1] => 
    [2] => 13.3 HOURS
    [3] => 
    [4] => 10.6 HOURS AGO
    [5] => 
    [6] => 8 HOURS AGO
    [7] => 
    [8] => 5.3 HOURS AGO
    [9] => 
    [10] => 2.6 HOURS AGO
    [11] => 
    [12] => CURRENT
)
```

Comment: This is more or less what I ended up with last time but I need it to insert the empty values dynamically, e.g. if I want the array to be 18 in length then add another empty value after every hour and if I want it to be 24 then add another one etc

Comment: What about my code isn't dynamic? See `if($i < count($array))`? Have you tested it with a different array length?

Comment: I want to be able to select the length and have a function insert spaces until the desired length is reached, neither your or my function does that.

Comment: @user1990896 Then I'm completely not understanding what you want. The example you posted in the comment under your question is exactly what my code does.

Comment: If I use `if($i < 24) {$tempArray[] = ' ';}` then all the spaces will be added at the end of the array, and I was the spaces to be disturbed evenly between all words.

Comment: But why would you add a static number?

Comment: Just as an example to test the function, with 25 it would insert 3 spaces between every string

Comment: So can we agree that no matter what size array you put into `$array`, it will work as desired?

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array(
    '16 HOURS',
    '13.3 HOURS',
    '10.6 HOURS AGO',
    '8 HOURS AGO',
    '5.3 HOURS AGO',
    '2.6 HOURS AGO',
    'CURRENT'
);


$newArray = array_combine(
        range(0,12,2),
        $myArray
    ) +
    array_fill_keys(
        range(1,12,2),
        ''
    )
;
ksort($newArray);

var_dump($newArray);
```